# how to convert the date format 101 in sql storedprocedure from xml document

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i wrote the following `procedure`... how will convert `date 101 format` here

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PenDataIns]
--[Begin]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
(
    @xmlData ntext = null

) As
--[Begin]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Declare @DocHandle int --Doc handle for P1 
DECLARE @Data_ins_error int

BEGIN TRANSACTION
--[Load data into respective XML document handle before processing]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @xmlData

--[Ecsstru]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


/*  Begin data transfer   */

BEGIN
 INSERT INTO AG_Data([PPO],
    [NUM],[TYPE],[DOB],[DOA],[DOR]) 

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/root/NewDataSet/Table',8) 
WITH
(
    [PPO] varchar(8) './PPO',
    [NUM] numeric(1,0) './NUM',
    [TYPE] varchar(3) './TYPE',
    [DOB] date './DOB',
    [DOA] date './DOA',
    [DOR] date './DOR')

end
```

Comment: What is not work for you? Do you get an error or...?

Comment: no i need to convert dateformat 101 for this line  [DOB] date './DOB',
how will convert this ?

Comment: What data type is DOB in AG_Data? What is the format of the date in the XML?

Comment: In sql DOB is date and i get a date from xml as string format.

Comment: In what string format? Is it `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: yes  it came like this format only

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine and does not need fixing. You have `yyyy-mm-dd` date format in your XML file and that is [exactly what it should be](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date) and it is what SQL Server needs to correctly interpret the date values in your XML file.

The dates in SQL Server is not stored with a specific format. How dates are presented to an end users is best done at the presentation layer where you can have different presentations depending on the locale settings for that user.

If you really want a specific date format when you query your date values you have to convert the values to a string using [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). For example `select convert(char(10), DateColumn, 101) as DateColumn`